# «Ничего не видно в эти проклятые очки!»

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление, выбор-варианта

Много раз смотрела этот старый советский мультфильм (["Петя и Красная Шапочка"](https://mults.info/mults/?id=929), 1958 г.), но только сегодня обратила внимание на слова Волка (~ 14.40).
*— Ничего не видно **в** эти проклятые **очки**!*

Я, конечно, не сказочный персонаж, но сказала бы по-другому: не видно в этих очках.
Так правильны слова Волка или нет? Может, тонкость есть какая? Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

У меня оно звучит, пусть и необычно.

Связано с "*смотреть **в** бинокль / подзорную трубу / телескоп*". Было сказано по аналогии с этим, ведь в очках тоже линзы, это тоже оптическое приспособление.

То есть волк хотел сказать, что он не может рассмотреть в этот оптический прибор. Не то, что он не видит, когда носит очки. Таким образом может подчёркивается, что он пытается рассмотреть что-то (Красную Шапочку) — как звёзды в телескоп. Тонкость имеется.

Comment: Спасибо за интересную трактовку.

Comment: oleedd, спасибо большое за советы по восстановлению работы моей страницы! Дело было в  браузере. Мой обновить не удалось, Chrome не помог, а вот в Яндексе всё заработало.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Обновлять не обязательно. Можно просто переустановить: https://www.google.com/intl/ru/chrome/ Менять браузер ради одного сайта очень неудобно.

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю... Проблема у меня возникла в браузере Самсунг Интернет, потом я установил Chrome, но ничего не изменилось. Да, хотелось бы работать в одном браузере.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Аа, так дело в телефоне. Мобильные браузеры отстают по функционалу от компьютерных, но проверил, и нужные команды в нём имеются: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=ru Там могут быть похожие, нужен этот. В Google Play на странице браузера должно писаться "Открыть", а не "Обновить" — тогда версия последняя.

Comment: Я так и делал с Google Chrome, он просто у меня был нерабочим, и сейчас снова попробовал, но в нём "Русский язык" не работает, и вообще очень странно выглядит. А мне бы хотелось восстановиться в моем привычном браузере.  Здесь, в Яндексе, например, я не могу скопировать из буфера обмена то, что мне требуется... Ладно, спасибо, я выхожу.

Comment: Если старая версия Android на телефоне, ниже необходимой, то браузер, как и другие программы, просто не будет обновляться. Так сделано, чтобы покупали новые телефоны. У меня сайт в Chrome на телефоне работает. Надо нажать на три точки, потом "Справка/отзыв", потом опять на три точки, и там можно посмотреть версию браузера. Какая она у Chrome?

Comment: Ради интереса установил Samsung Internet Browser, и там сайт тоже работает. В конце настроек можно посмотреть версию браузера. Какая она?

Comment: У Хрома версия 46.0.2490.76    у Самсунга не могу найти, пишет "данное приложение не совместимо с вашим устройством, обратитесь к разработчикам", хотя всё остальное на нём работает как обычно.

Comment: Нашел у самсунга  9.2.10.15

Comment: У Chrome у меня 96.0.4664.104, далеко уже ушла. У Samsung — 16.0.2.19, прилично старше. Надо менять телефон или перепрошивать, в мастерской или самостоятельно — по интернет-гайдам, что рискованно (телефон может прийти в негодность, если что-то пойдёт не так, это тоже сделано специально).

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за учвстие и рекомендации!

Comment: Что для Samsung, что для Chrome требуется Android 6.0+. Оно так и будет подниматься, это сговор с Гугл.

Comment: У меня андроид 5.0.2

Comment: Недавно этого было вполне достаточно, а теперь они вообще обнаглели.

Answer (score 2):

Это устаревшее употребление. В древних словарях оно упоминается. Для примера, в словаре XVIII в.:

> ОЧКИ́, о́в, мн. Надѣл он себѣ на нос очки, чтоб лучше меня
> разсмотрѣть. Гулливер II 36. Зрѣние мое тупѣет, говорит Ирена.
> Употребляй очки! говорит Эскулап. Ипп. I 204. ◊ В очках (быть, делать
> ..). Дряхлой рукой и в очках рисует. Кнт. Сат. V 123. Наконец явился
> .. Борк, сухощавой старик в очках. Крм. ПРП VI 296. ◊ **В очки
> (читать, смотреть, видеть ..). Глаза худо и в очки видят.** АК X 327.
> Взгляните на меня: я в двадцать лѣт старик; .. Смотрю в очки, ношу
> парик. Крм. Ст. 123.

В словарях середины прошлого века я такого употребления уже не нахожу, но в литературе иногда встречается. Приведу пару цитат:

> В очки только красивое видно — так Сазгин говорит. (Г. Гор, 1940)

> У нее душа болела смотреть на его муки : прибежит с мороза заледенелый,
> в очки ничего не видит... (Н. Кузьмин, 1983)

Comment: Спасибо, Медведик!